# What is the fastest way to locate an image inside a larger image?

Tags: image-processing

let b =

[image]

---

let c =

[image]

---

How to do:

```
find[c,b]
```

that returns the bounding box of `c` in `b`?

**Notes**

- Original `b` is not scaled, this is only the case in this post.
- **(Update: this may actually not be the case.)** Because `b` contains an exact copy of `c`, this can be thought of as a problem of finding a submatrix in a larger matrix.

**Links to original images**

- http://portfusion.sourceforge.net/i/m1/B.png
- http://portfusion.sourceforge.net/i/m1/C.png

**Update**

Here are the results so far:

[image]

**Final Result** (using Heike's answer)

[image]

Comment: If your actual images are not scaled with respect to each other, can you post them?  Allowing rescaling is significantly more difficult than searching for an exact image.

Comment: @Szabolcs I just posted the originals AND updated `B` once because the first `B` I posted was actually scaled so I updated `B` with a smaller image with no scaling between `B` and `C`.

Comment: I gave up on `ImageAlign`, and I rewrote the answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `ImageCorrelate`, you can do something like

```
bbox[img_, crop_] := {#, # + Reverse@ImageDimensions[crop] - 1} &@
  Position[ImageData@
     Binarize[
      ImageCorrelate[img, crop, SquaredEuclideanDistance, 
       Padding -> None], .001], 0][[1]]
```

Example

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}]
crop = ImageTake[img, {40, 80}, {141, 200}]

bbox[img, crop]
```

> ```
> {{40, 141}, {80, 200}}
> ```

**Edit**

In response to the OP's question,here is an explanation of how `bbox` works.

`ImageCorrelate` in `bbox` creates a new image by calculating the Euclidean distance between `crop` and each of the sub images of `img` with the same dimensions as `crop`. The option `Padding -> None` is to make sure that the pixel at `{i,j}` in the result of `ImageCorrelate` corresponds to the sub image whose upper left corner is at position `{i,j}` in the original image.

The Euclidean distance between two images is zero only if they are the same, so to find the position of `crop` in `img` we just need to extract the position of the pixels with value `{0.,0.,0.}` from the image data of `ImageCorrelate` which is what `Position[ImageData@Binarize[....]], 0]` does.

This will give us the position of the upper left corner of `crop`. The lower right corner is then the upper-left corner plus the dimensions of `crop` (note that since `ImageDimensions` returns `{number of cols, number of rows}`, and the bounding box is given as `{{rowMin, colMin}, {roxMaw, colMax}}` we need to reverse `ImageDimensions`)

**Edit 2**

As Szabolcs pointed out, the cut off in `Binarize` is somewhat arbitrary, and might cause false positives. As an alternative you could do something like this instead, which would find the best fit in the image:

```
bbox[img_, crop_] := {#, # + Reverse@ImageDimensions[crop] - 1} &@
 (Position[#, Min[#]][[1]] &@
   ImageData[ColorConvert[
     ImageCorrelate[img, crop, SquaredEuclideanDistance, 
      Padding -> None], "Graylevel"]])
```

Comment: This is the only working solution so far :) and it is much much faster than ImageAlign (the result which even needs further processing to get to a bbox).

Comment: Could you explain the inner workings of `bbox`?

Comment: Oh nuts, I just spent half an hour on something like this.  I thought you were out. ;-p

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in version 7; is there a simple fix?

Comment: @CetinSert please see edit

Comment: I don't like that `Binarize`.  It is a point of failure because of the rather arbitrary threshold.  Can you search for the minimum value instead, as I did in my (now deleted solution)?  I am afraid someone might come up with an example on which this'll fail.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It looks like in version 7, `ImageCorrelate` only accepts a 2 dimensional numerical matrix for the kernel. You could try to convert the both `img` and `crop` to grayscale and to use `ImageCorrelate[img, ImageData[crop],...]` on the converted images (although I don't know if you can specify the distance function in v7).

Comment: @Szabolcs I've added a new version of bbox using the minimum value

Comment: @Szabolcs thank you for pointing output Binarize.

Comment: @Heike, updated the question with a final screenshot using ImageCorrelate.

Answer (score 6):

If your final assertion is true:

> Because b contains an exact copy of c, this can be thought of as a
>   problem of finding a submatrix in a larger matrix.

You will find your answer here:

[A fast implementation in Mathematica for Position2D](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8364804/618728)

---

Since your images are apparently *not* exact, you can find the position of the upper left corner of the sample with correlation:

```
b = Import["http://portfusion.sourceforge.net/i/m1/B.png"];
c = Import["http://portfusion.sourceforge.net/i/m1/C.png"];

full = ImageData[ColorConvert[b, "Grayscale"]];
sample = ImageData[ColorConvert[c, "Grayscale"]];

cor = ListCorrelate[1/(sample /. 0. -> 1.0*^-6), full];

Position[cor, Min@cor]
```

> {{94, 88}}

The correlation looks like this:

```
cor // Rescale // Image
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I just took a look at that post myself for some reason none of the examples seem to work as of now. I copy paste these images using the snapshot tool of Acrobat. Perhaps the internal data are not exactly the same (despite the appearance), rendering my final assertion actually false.

Comment: I got Position2D to work if a binarize the images beforehand.

Comment: @Cetin how does its speed compare to the `ListCorrelate` method?

Answer (score 6):

For (not necessarily) more complicated cases, you may want to have a look at the geometric transformation functions in Mathematica.

```
img = Import["~/temp/geomtrafo.png"]; (* The image *)
crop = ImageCrop[img, {100, 100}]; (* Crop small portion *)
FindGeometricTransform[img, crop, Transformation -> "Similarity"][[2]]
```

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Notice the two numbers in the `TransformationFunction`? These are the lower left coordinates of the cropped image in the large one. I used the parameter `Transformation -> "Similarity"` here, which considers rotations, translations, and scalings; there are more basic and more complicated ones available, refer to the help function of `FindGeometricTransform`.

I'm afraid I don't know how to extract these numbers properly from there, but that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: "I'm afraid I don't know how to extract these numbers properly from there, but that shouldn't be an issue." post the output of `FindGeometricTransform[. . .] // InputForm` and we should be able to fix that.

Comment: When I do `b = "http://portfusion.sourceforge.net/i/m1/B.png" // Import;`
`c = "http://portfusion.sourceforge.net/i/m1/C.png" // Import;`
`FindGeometricTransform[b, c, "Transformation" -> "Similarity"]` I get the error: `Images ### and ### do not share any corresponding points`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That's why I said "properly". Using patterns and `Part` will of course work, but it's pretty hacky.

Comment: @CetinSert Yes, I'm able to reproduce that, but I don't know why it occurs, sorry. I'm not using image functions very often. Read my post as a helper until somebody can give you a decent solution.

Comment: @David TransformationMatrix seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

As a footnote: I remember my problems with `ImageAlign` [before](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38/imagealign-doesnt-always-work-correctly)  were caused by the fact that the images were simply too small. So if we make them bigger, it should work better.

```
bin = Binarize[
  ImageAlign[ImageResize[all, Scaled[2]], 
             ImageResize[part, Scaled[2]]]]
```

where 'all' and 'part' are the two images.

[image: imagealign]

and it seems to work.

```
First[Position[ImageData[bin], 1]]
```

returns row and column:

```
{187, 175}
```