# How can I find a particular character in an image that has many similar Chinese characters?

Tags: image-processing

The Chinese characters "竟" and "竞"  are very similar in their appearance. I am trying to find "竟" in the following picture.

I tried use `TextRecognize` but it didn't work. Can you tell me any other way?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please take a look at the rendered font and the character in your image. They are quite different http://i.stack.imgur.com/Duen5.png

Comment: @belisarius you have the eyes of a hawk... :)

Comment: See also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1911/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-locate-an-image-inside-a-larger-image

Comment: As a native speaker, I'd say "just look at them" :D

Comment: @belisarius It probably because some CJK fonts are bitmap when used with small fontsize, but automatically turn to outline type when the fontsize is big enough. If I remember correctly, bitmap fonts will be easier to recognize for small size complex glyphs.

Comment: Something along the following lines might solve your problem:

`image = <insert image here> // ColorNegate`, followed by 
`charimage = Rasterize[竟, ImageSize -> 12] // ColorNegate`, followed by 
`ImageCorrelate[image, charimage] // ColorNegate`.

This finds 2 instances of the sought after character in the block of characters at the top of the original image. You would need to post-process this result to transform it to whatever your preferred format is.

More generally, you have to try various `ImageSize` options to find the character size that gives the best match.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you've got the image in `i1`, and the character in `char`, then this might work:

```
{charBig, imageBig} = ImageResize[#, Scaled[5]] & /@ {char, i1};
ImageAlign[imageBig, charBig, Background -> Gray]
```

[image: chinchar]

**Edit**

However, I don't think this is the right way to do it. Instead, I made two binarized images.

```
i1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/GR1Ml.jpg"];
i2 = Binarize@i1;
char =  ImageTrim[i2, {{464, 111}, {473, 120}}]; 
     (* since question didn't provide a suitable character to look for *)
width = First[ImageDimensions[char]];
charData = ImageData[char];
```

then used `ImageFilter` to find the location(s) of the character:

```
foundLocations = 
 PixelValuePositions[
   ImageFilter[Boole[# == charData] &, i2, (width - 1)/2], 1]
```

> {{256, 170}, {469, 116}}

Then I can display the results like this:

```
ImageCompose[
    HighlightImage[i2, foundLocations, 
        Method -> {"DiskMarkers", width}],
    {i2, 0.5}]
```

which isn't brilliant, but I can't get translucent markers with `HighlightImage` yet.

[image: found chars]

Of course, if the big image doesn't contain the little one, none of this would work...

Comment: Another option is like in the "Applications" section of `ImageCorrelate` (a la Waldo)

Comment: Please add the loaders for `char` and `ì1` for completeness :D