# How to make a function for image recognition

Tags: computational-geometry

[image: Example 1]

For example given a big set of random points, and I extract a small section of the random set of points, how can I find the small set on the big set?

As a first approach I tried to do a Delaunay triangulation, on the random points and then on the small set of points and the compare both the images, but is there any image pattern recognition in Mathematica?

As a first approach I construct a Delaunay mesh in the whole set, and then in the extracted part of the image create again the triangular mesh and then try to compare them. But I don not know how to do it. Here is the link of the code fore the mesh: [How can select a specific triangle in my Delaunay mesh?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/201490/how-can-select-a-specific-triangle-in-my-delaunay-mesh)

Comment: What do you know about the extracted set of points? Are they the same size/scale as in the bigger image? Can they be rotated?

Comment: What you know about the points its that they come from the bigger set. The sub image can be rotates any degree, for size and scale can be another issue, but in theory the small set of points would be a sub image of the big one so, the scale and size can vary.

Comment: This Q&A - https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1911/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-locate-an-image-inside-a-larger-image - may provide some avenues to explore.