# How can I select a specific triangle in my Delaunay mesh?

Tags: computational-geometry

Here is the code I am working with. I create a list of random coordinates, then I create a triangular mesh with the code:

```
list = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {10, 2}]
mesh = DelaunayMesh[
  list,
  MeshCellLabel -> {0 -> "Index"},
  PlotTheme -> "Lines",
  MeshCellHighlight -> {{1, All} -> Green, {0, All} -> Black},
  Frame -> True
  ]
```

[image]

How can I select a specific triangle? For example, how can I select the triangle with vertices `{10,7,2}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** A more convenient version that allows the vertex indices in any order:

```
ClearAll[vToF]
vToF[vl : {__}] := KeyMap[ Sort, vertexToFace][Sort[vl]];

HighlightMesh[mesh, {Style[{2, vToF[{10, 9, 4}]}, Red], 
  Style[{2, vToF[{8, 1, 5}]}, Yellow]}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
SeedRandom[1]
list = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {10, 2}];
mesh = DelaunayMesh[list, MeshCellLabel -> {0 -> "Index"}, 
    PlotTheme -> "Lines", 
    MeshCellHighlight -> {{1, All} -> Green, {0, All} -> Black}, 
    Frame -> True]
```

You can create an association mapping face vertices to face indices using the property `"FaceVertexConnectivityRules"`:

```
vertexToFace = Association[Reverse /@ mesh["FaceVertexConnectivityRules"]]
```

> <|{3, 8, 5} -> 1, {8, 3, 7} -> 2, {2, 5, 10} -> 3, {1, 5, 8} -> 
>     4, {10, 5, 1} -> 5, {8, 9, 1} -> 6, {9, 7, 4} -> 7, {7, 9, 8} -> 
>     8, {10, 4, 6} -> 9, {4, 10, 9} -> 10, {10, 6, 2} -> 
>     11, {9, 10, 1} -> 12|>

```
HighlightMesh[mesh, Style[{2, vertexToFace[{3, 8, 5}]}, Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: How did you know about the faces vertex coordinates rules? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: @LasdesNestor Yes, these things are mostly undocumented. This is why Mathematica.StackExchange is so valuable: People try a lot of spelunking and also a few of the developers are around here.

Comment: @LasdesNestor,  try `mesh["Properties"]` to see a long list of properties. Since they are not documented it is by trial and luck that you discover quiet a few useful properties.

Comment: Is there a way to extract that particular triangle, so I can compare them with the other ones? Let say that I select a triangle and I want to check if the triangle is part of the original plot.

Comment: @LasdesNestor,  the triangle (polygon) can be obtained using `MeshPrimitives[mesh, {2,1}]` or using  `MeshPrimitives[mesh, {2,vertexToFace[{3,8,5}]}]`.

Comment: Is there a possible way to tell mathematica to look for the extracted triangles in the whole plot?

Comment: @LasdesNestor, not sure I understand; can you eloborate? "whole plot" is `mesh`?  and "to look for the extracted triangles" means something other than `Highlight`?

Comment: Well, How can I tell mathematica that the polygon I selected is part of the Dealunay mesh I created? in a graphical way, beacuse if I use `RegionQ[]` the output would be true, but How can I see it graphically?

Comment: LasdesNestor, something like: `polygons=MeshCells[mesh, 2];
selected= MeshCells[mesh,{2, vToF[{10,9,4}]}]; MemberQ[polygons,selected]`?  (This of course will always give `True` because `selected` is selected from `polygons`)